# columnar cursor motions in vim?

Tags: vim, editor

I'm wondering if there's a command in Vim I'm missing that does columnar motion.  What I'm thinking of is common in some spreadsheets, where there's a key combination that will take you downward in the column to either the next blank cell, or if you're in a blank cell then it will take you to the next non-blank cell.  Some text may illustate:

```
a-------
-------
-------
b-------

c-------
-------
-------
d-------


e-------
-------
```

What I'm looking for is most efficient way to move from a to b, from b to c, from c to d, from d to e.  I know this can be done using / searches, but is there a more efficient way using something analous to the line-based motion commands?  Seems like there should be, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to jump between non-empty lines:

```
:nmap j /^.\+$<CR>
```

Comment: Sudhansu -- Thanks a lot, I may end up doing something like that.  But I'd like to avoid messing with mappings if there's a good built-in way to make these movements.

Comment: @Herbert - No, I don't think vim has any built in way to do it.

Comment: @Sudhansu -- Thanks, there's some comfort in knowing I'm not missing something.  Now I guess question becomes merely, What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this fits your request exactly but vim has [sentence](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#sentence), [paragraph](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#paragraph), and [section](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#section) movement keys built-in.  In your case, I think you probably want the paragraph ( '{' and '}' ) or section ( '[' and ']' ) motion keys.